# Limit the rows for a column of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like

```
MyTable (id, name, counter, createDate)
```

I can order the query like

```
Select * from MyTable order by counter;
```

I am just wondering, is it possible to limit the number of rows for each day. For example, I want the rows from the above query but I do not want them more than 10 rows from each day. So if it has 100 days of entry, I will be looking for less or equal to 10(row)x100(day) rows.

I am really not that good at SQL. Any help/suggestion would be really appreciatable.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?`

Comment: is createDate the date you mean?  is it a date or a datetime?

Comment: @jarlh latest MySQL.. 8.0.

Comment: @ysth this is datetime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results). I hope you can manage `datetime -> date` conversion with [reference to docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).

Answer (score 1):

10 rows per day with the least `counter`:

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY createDate 
                                         ORDER BY counter) rn
              FROM MyTable )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 10
```

If `createDate` has DATETIME/TIMESTAMP datatype then

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(createDate) 
                                         ORDER BY counter) rn
              FROM MyTable )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY createDate ORDER BY createDate) r, c.* FROM MyTable T c) WHERE r <= 10
```